FastLED with WS2812B 241228
Hello Arduino Stack Exchange forum,
Learning how to use the FastLED to control a string of 150 WS2812B LEDs
Code copied herewith below compiles and operates as expected.
Trying to figure out how to turn on LEDs with different colors,
say, alternating green and red.
Thanks.
Allen Pitts
Dallas TX
PS What is the CRGB suffix before the three three-digit numbers that specify the color?
/*
from How To Control WS2812B Individually Addressable LEDs using Arduino
https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/how-to-control-ws2812b-individually-addressable-leds-using-arduino/
In this sketch first learned how to turn on twenty LEDs using statements for
each LED. Then figured out how to turn them off: "leds[i] = (0, 0, 0);"
The learned how to turn them on using FOR staement.
Next step Learn how to turn the LEDs on having different colors.

Last change:  NUM_LEDS to 150 and 
 for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
    // turn off 
This works on the LED strip marked "Alito WS2812B"    

*/

#include <FastLED.h>

#define LED_PIN     3
#define NUM_LEDS    150

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup() {

  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, LED_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  
}

void loop() {
 /*
  leds[0] = CRGB(255, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);  
  leds[1] = CRGB(0, 255, 0);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[2] = CRGB(0, 0, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[3] = CRGB(150, 0, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[4] = CRGB(255, 200, 20);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[5] = CRGB(85, 60, 180);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[6] = CRGB(50, 255, 20);
  FastLED.show();
  leds[7] = CRGB(255, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);  
  leds[8] = CRGB(0, 255, 0);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[9] = CRGB(0, 0, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[10] = CRGB(150, 0, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[11] = CRGB(255, 200, 20);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[12] = CRGB(85, 60, 180);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[13] = CRGB(50, 255, 20);
  FastLED.show();
  leds[14] = CRGB(0, 255, 0);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[15] = CRGB(0, 0, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[16] = CRGB(150, 0, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[17] = CRGB(255, 200, 20);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[18] = CRGB(85, 60, 180);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[19] = CRGB(50, 255, 20);
  FastLED.show();
  */

  for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    // turn on
    leds[i] = CRGB(0, 255, 0);
    // Show the leds
    FastLED.show();
    delay(50);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
    // turn off 
    leds[i] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
    // Show the leds
    FastLED.show();
    delay(10);

  }
}


What happens when you run your code?

the leds[] array is an in-memory representation of the actual LEDs ... fill the array with color values and then call FastLED.show(); to copy the array into the LED strip ... your question is not about the Arduino ... it is a general programming question

research the for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) { ... learn what it does ... it is in the C++ programming world

CRGB seems to be a struct which basically holds a value for Red, Green, and Blue values for a pixel.
From pixeltypes.h in the FastLED library:
/// Representation of an RGB pixel (Red, Green, Blue)
struct CRGB {
    union {
        struct {
            union {
                uint8_t r;
                uint8_t red;
            };
            union {
                uint8_t g;
                uint8_t green;
            };
            union {
                uint8_t b;
                uint8_t blue;
            };
        };
        uint8_t raw[3];
    };

As for the rest of your question, there isn't really a question there. To get an answer you need to post a question, stating:

What you attempted
What you expected to happen
What actually happened

You said:

Code copied herewith below compiles and operates as expected.

So it is hard to progress from there. The code compiles and works, so what is the problem?
